# Is it possible to call (p/invoke) c# method from c++ when you have native file reference for Blazor?

Tags: c#, c++, blazor, pinvoke, webassembly

I have a very basic knowledge of c++ and c programming languages.
After I have seen some videos from Steve Sanderson and Matthew Leibowitz on ASP.NET Community Standup.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVWQkpcVEWQ&t=2957s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gwSU3oaMV8

I decided to do an experimental project and try a little about the concepts that have been described over there. So what I want to do is to pass byte array(video file) to native code and take out all the frames from inside and send the output back to c# code so I can use them in skiasharp canvas.

I have managed to pass byte array to native code, but I couldn't manage to call c# method from native c code. I have tried reverse p / invoke, if that is what is called :)I am trying to pass a delegate to c code like this

**c code**

```
extern "C"
{
void test_class_callmycallback(
      void callback(int,int))
  {
    callback(3,5);
  }
}
```

this is just for testing purposes normally what I want to do is sth like this.

```
void test_class_renderpicture(void *obj, void (*func)(uint8_t *, int))
  {
    ((TestClass *)obj)->getBytesWithCallback(func);
  }
```

**And on the c# side**

```
        [DllImport("Test")]
        static extern void test_class_callmycallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] CallbackDelegate func);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public delegate void CallbackDelegate(int arg1, int arg2);

        public void RenderPicture()
        {
            var managedDel = new CallbackDelegate(Multiply);

             test_class_callmycallback(Multiply);
            //RenderPictureDelegate managedDelegate = new RenderPictureDelegate(RenderPictureCallback);
            //test_class_renderpicture(this.handle, managedDelegate);
        }
        public void Multiply(int a,int b)
        {
            var c=a * b; 
        }
```

and I use this command for emscripten compilation.

`emcc  myfile.cpp -shared -o Test.o`

and added this to my blazor project

`<ItemGroup> <NativeFileReference Include="Test.o" /> </ItemGroup>`

everything compiles fine, but on the runtime, I got this error.

> Assertion at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/metadata/loader.c:1806, condition
> `' not met 573846   @   dotnet..bnoeqi2kuy.js:1430
> _emscripten_asm_const_int @   dotnet..bnoeqi2kuy.js:5673 $wasm_trace_logger   @   02e96b9a:0x228b7a
> $eglib_log_adapter    @   02e96b9a:0xc102f
> $monoeg_g_logstr  @   02e96b9a:0x20754f
> $monoeg_g_logv_nofree @   02e96b9a:0x2074f3
> $monoeg_assertion_message @   02e96b9a:0x2075d0
> $mono_assertion_message   @   02e96b9a:0x207619

The first question is if it is possible to call(invoke) c# method from c/c++ native code, and if it is possible how can I do it in blazor project? Thank you for reading it.

PS: I don't think [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] and [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] attributes are necessary. But all the examples for classical dllimport from file do that. But emscripten always gives a warning whenever you want to use __stdcall or __declspec(dllexport). Are those attributes necessary for blazor web assembly project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,
I have found out the solution after couple of tests.
hope this can help to someone else.
I have found the similar issue on dotnet runtime issues page.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60824

here is a good checklist when you want to pass function pointer to native library. I am quoting from the thread

> To use native code make sure that:
>
> 1. You install the wasm-tools workload
> 2. You build with the property WasmBuildNative set to true. (ie: dotnet
>    build and dotnet run with -p:WasmBuildNative=true or set it in your
>    .csproj)
> 3. You must label managed methods that are passed to C++ with a
>    [UnmanagedCallersOnly] attribute.
> 4. The method marked with the UnmanagedCallersOnly attribute must be
>    static. That means to call an instance method on a razor page you
>    will need to pass a GCHandle for the instance to C++, and then pass
>    it back to native. Or use some other method to identify the instance
>    of the Razor page.
> 5. The method marked with [DllImport] must use a C# 9.0 function
>    pointer rather than a delegate type for the callback argument.
> 6. But there's currently an issue with using C# function pointer types
>    in [DllImport] methods on WebAssembly. So we have to use IntPtr in
>    the method signature on the managed side instead of delegate
>    *unmanaged<int, void>

for me the critical parts were number 3,4 and number 6. So at the end i have managed to fix it with this code.

on c++ side

```
typedef void (*TestCallBack)(int args1, int args2);

class TestClass
{       // The class
public: // Access specifier
        // Attribute (int variable)
  TestClass(int value) { this->value = value; }
  int getValue() { 
    return this->value; 
  }
  void setBytes(uint8_t *fileBytes, int length)
  {
    this->file_bytes = fileBytes;
    this->file_length = length;
  }

  uint8_t *getBytes()
  {
    return this->file_bytes;
  }
  void setCallback(TestCallBack callback)
  {
    this->callback = callback;
    callback(1,2);
  }

private:
  int value;
  uint8_t *file_bytes;
  int file_length;
  TestCallBack callback;
  void *callbackState;
};

extern "C"
{
  void *test_class_new(int value) { return new TestClass(value); }
  void test_class_delete(void *obj) { delete (TestClass *)obj; }
  int test_class_getvalue(void *obj) { return ((TestClass *)obj)->getValue(); }
  void test_class_setbytes(void *obj, uint8_t *file_bytes, int file_length)
  {
    ((TestClass *)obj)->setBytes(file_bytes, file_length);
  }
  uint8_t *test_class_getbytes(void *obj) { return ((TestClass *)obj)->getBytes(); }
  void test_class_setcallback(
      void *obj, TestCallBack callback)
  {
    ((TestClass *)obj)->setCallback(callback);
  }
}
```

on c#

```
 public class TestClassRef : IDisposable
    {
        nint handle;

        [DllImport("Test")]
        extern static nint test_class_new(int value);

        [DllImport("Test")]
        extern static void test_class_delete(nint obj);

        [DllImport("Test")]
        extern static int test_class_getvalue(nint obj);

        [DllImport("Test")]
        extern static void test_class_setbytes(nint obj, IntPtr file_bytes, int file_length);

        [DllImport("Test")]
        extern static void test_class_setcallback(nint obj, IntPtr callback);



        public TestClassRef(int value)
        {
            this.handle = test_class_new(value);
        }
        public int Value => test_class_getvalue(this.handle);
        IntPtr unmanagedFileBytes = default(IntPtr);
        public void SetBytes(byte[] bytes)
        {
            this.unmanagedFileBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedFileBytes, bytes.Length);
            test_class_setbytes(this.handle, unmanagedFileBytes, bytes.Length);
        }
        public void SetCallback()
        {

            unsafe
            {
                delegate * unmanaged<int,int, void> fn = &Multiply;
                test_class_setcallback(this.handle, (IntPtr)fn);
            }
        }
        [UnmanagedCallersOnly]
        private static void Multiply(int a, int b)
        {
            var c = a * b;
        }
        public void CleanBytes()
        {
            if (this.unmanagedFileBytes != default(IntPtr))
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedFileBytes);
            }

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            CleanBytes();
            test_class_delete(this.handle);
        }
    }
```